# Understanding Oracle's Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos, oracle

I've been using Java on OS X for many, many years and recently when Apple stopped including Java by default I let the OS go and install it for me (Apple's variety, of course).

So now I'm using OS X 10.8 and I need to install Java 7 so I just got Oracle's Update 15 in DMG form and ran the installer.  It updated my /usr/bin/java (and related files) to point here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Tracing this back to '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions' everything either points to 'Current' or 'CurrentJDK', the former being a link to 'A' (which is Oracle's Java 7, from what I can tell, not sure why it is 'A') and the latter being a link to Apple's Java 6 in '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk'.

Now this is all really confusing but this isn't even my question yet.  It appears there is a Java 7 installed here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A
```

But there is also a Java 7 installed here:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk
```

Finding 'java' in both and printing out the version yields the same version and build (java version "1.7.0_15"), however, when hashing the files they are different.

So does this mean Oracle installed Java 7 in two different places?  If so, why?  Which am I supposed to use?  And why do some things still point to Java 6 (CurrentJDK).

I've looked on Oracle's website but nothing there clears anything up.

Comment: Asked exactly the same question i want to. I was really confused by the "2" JRE in my Mac. Your description is clear and clean. Thanks for asking:)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Oracle's JVM is only installed in one location. You've been misled!

As you've noted, the Java commands in `/usr/bin` are symlinks to binaries in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`. The binaries within that directory are stub applications that determine which Java VM to use*, and then exec the corresponding real binary within that VM version. This is why all of the binaries within `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands` are almost identical in size, despite the fact that you'd expect them to be implementing quite different functionality.

You can see this in action by using `dtrace`:

```
mrowe@angara:~$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::posix_spawn:entry { trace(copyinstr(arg1)); }' -c "/usr/bin/java -version"
dtrace: description 'syscall::posix_spawn:entry ' matched 1 probe
dtrace: pid 44727 has exited
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  8    619                posix_spawn:entry   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

The given `dtrace` invocation prints out the path argument to `posix_spawn` when it is called by `java -version`. In my case the stub application has found Apple's Java 1.6 runtime in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk` and is invoking that version of the `java` command.

The stub binaries also have another benefit: when they detect that no Java VM is installed they will prompt the user to install one.

As for the `CurrentJDK` symlink, as best as I can tell this for sake of backwards-compatibility with the past when Apple was the only source of the JVM on OS X.

---

* A combination of factors are considered when determining which Java VM should be used. `JAVA_HOME` is used if set (try `JAVA_HOME=/tmp java`). If `JAVA_HOME` is not set then the list of all virtual machines on the system is discovered. The `JAVA_VERSION` and `JAVA_ARCH` environment variables are used, if set, to filter the list of virtual machines to a particular version and supported architecture. The resulting list is then sorted by architecture (preferring 64-bit over 32-bit) and version (newer is better), and the best match is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even think to look at the size of the files. I can investigate a bit more on my own, but where you say "stub applications that determine which Java VM to use" ... how do they make this determination? Hopefully it's with JAVA_HOME but maybe something else?

Comment: A combination of factors are considered. JAVA_HOME is used if set (try `JAVA_HOME=/tmp java`). If JAVA_HOME is not set then the list of all virtual machines on the system is discovered. The JAVA_VERSION and JAVA_ARCH environment variables are used, if set, to filter the list of virtual machines to a particular version and supported architecture. The resulting list is then sorted by architecture (preferring 64-bit over 32-bit) and version (newer is better), and the best match is returned.

Answer (score 11):

The Oracle Java 7 *JRE* (i.e. the one that is used by the web browser plugin to run applets and Java Web Start) installs itself in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`, and it is this one that any automatic updates will affect.  The *JDK* (the one you download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) installs by creating a directory under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, and it's up to you to update this yourself.  You can have multiple JDK versions installed side by side but only one "public" JRE under `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` (which will correspond to the latest installed JDK or a later version if it has been auto-updated since).

As explained by bdash, the commands under `/usr/bin` are stubs that delegate to whichever JDK/JRE is pointed to by the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, or if that is not set then they will pick the most appropriate Java to run.  You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home` to see which one the stubs would pick.  If *no* Java is installed the stubs will offer to install the latest Apple Java 6 (as far as I know they will *not* offer to install Java 7).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and that makes sense.  I'll have to test the JAVA_HOME var and java_home bin to make sure I can get it to work as expected.

Comment: @rjcarr I realise my answer wasn't perfectly clear - the stubs will always respect JAVA_HOME - running `/usr/libexec/java_home` shows you which one it would pick if JAVA_HOME were _not_ set.

Comment: @bdash and Ian really appreciated your answers. I arrived at this post for a DIFFERRENT reason, I managed to mess up my Java install by mangling/misunderstanding the various symlinks and stubs. In case others hit this problem, my errors while running ant were "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile, at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:663)" and "There has been an error prior to that: java.lang.AssertionError: Platform not recognized at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:73)" - Phew!

Comment: @MarkBennett: This has come full circle.  I'm the original poster of this question almost 2 years ago, just got the same error you are getting after installing yosemite, and was led back to my same post!  But I can't seem to get this fixed; the 'java_home' command doesn't seem to exist on yosemite.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @rjcarr this is why I'm a bit reluctant to upgrade to Yosemite.  I'm sorely tempted, but Java and command line developer tools get messed up every time I do a major upgrade.  I'm getting use to it, I know to install Xcode and command line tools, and the absurd command-line accept license thing.  But still other times various ancillary tools are messed up too.  OS X used to awesome for developers out-of-the-box.  I still like it, but it's not how it used to be.  I'm sure each change had some rationale, but the sum and direction is sad.

Comment: @MarkBennett: Yeah, actually, this java issue was my second problem.  The first problem is that GD isn't compiled correctly into PHP.  I agree, every time I go through problems, but every time I seem to do the upgrade within a few weeks of release.  Masochist, I guess. :)

Answer (score 5):

I find this post:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html
The /usr/libexec/java_home tool dynamically finds the top Java version specified in Java Preferences for the current user.